# How to replace 2-byte English characters with 1-byte English characters?

Tags: java

It's a unicode English character and I'm not sure what to call it exactly.
Below is the English text source and the desired result.

source = "Kep ’  Collab"

i want result = "KepStreet Cat`s Club Collab"

Comment: hello and welcome to SO. Please first read some guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. After that please share your code in which you were trying to solve this issue, or any errors you encountered.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to do "unicode normalization". It is not quite as trivial at is seems: https://towardsdatascience.com/what-on-earth-is-unicode-normalization-56c005c55ad0

Comment: fascynacja I don't know the problem, so I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @JOJU it seems that you want to replace an apostrophe "'" character with an accent "`"? This would seem wrong to me...

Comment: See https://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_02B0.html for the names of these symbols.

Comment: Changed the encoding method to unicode mb4. Normalization couldn't solve all my problems. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for the example you provided, the conversion can be done by normalising the text to the compatibility decomposition form. The weird-looking, non ASCII letters are "mathematical bold" letters, as Unicode calls them. These are *compatibility equivalent* to their ASCII counterparts.

In Java, you do normalisation with the [`Normalizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Normalizer.html) class.

```
String normalised = Normalizer.normalize(yourString, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
```

Learn more about how normalisation forms [here](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/).

That said, other characters in your string might also have a compatibility decomposed form. This will change those characters too, which might be undesirable.